# Google bigtable-storagecapacity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I know how to create table in Google Bigtable. How much data can I store while staying within the free quota?

Comment: Could you please explain your question in more detail? What do you mean with "free cost"?

Comment: Is this about App Engine? Please tag it accordingly

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you want the [quotas for the App Engine datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Datastore).